# How should I fill a void in my slab/CMU foundation?

Tags: repair, foundation, slab

My rental property has a void in the CMU/slab foundation that is leading to a water intrusion issue.  I need advice on how to effectively force hydaraulic cement into a small hole to fill the voids.  I was thinking some sort of large syringe type device, but can't find anything that could be used for this application.

Comment: Pictures? How big is the hole/void?

Comment: Hydraulic cement usually holds better if the hole/crack is bigger on the inside, a reverse V.  If the hole is bigger inside, maybe a pasty/piping/frosting bag might work.

Answer (score 0):

Large syringe? try a mechanic's syringe.  eg: aliexpress.com/item/1005005682864385.html cement/grout is probably going to ruin the inside surface

If you need higher pressure (or want ot save money) spoon cement/grout into an empty caulk tube (use a metal rod to force the piston out the back) and use a caulk gun to pressurise it.